# What's Waking My Computer (from Hibernate)?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I have two desktops, the one I'm working on is a Win 7 [ASUS MB](https://superuser.com/questions/782619/whats-waking-up-my-pc/) has the problem, the other was reported [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9fd528a4-fbd1-4813-964a-1cd8225de231/computer-waking-up-at-night?).

All the checks in the first link above were done.

The first event log entry for the rogue power up was for the APC UPS: "PowerEvent handled successfully by the service." The security auditing for event 4672 is the same whether the rogue presses the button or I did.

However, the second system entry for the rogue power up is

TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper 
   param2 stop 
   param3 0x40030011 
   param4 Operating System: Network Connectivity (Planned) 
   param5 None

For the human power up there's

param1 TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper 
  param2 running

POWERCFG DEVICEDISABLEWAKE disables the device from waking the system from a sleep state, but what about from hibernation?

powercfg -lastwake provides no help.